# Implementing custom loss function in MatConvNet

Tags: deep-learning, matconvnet

I want to implement a custom loss function (from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00909) in MatConvNet.

My code uses the DagNN wrapper. I want to modify the class `SegmentationLoss()` to use a custom loss function, `custom_loss()` instead of `vl_nnloss()`. For the `forward()` pass, `custom_loss()` returns the calculated loss value.

What I don't understand is what `custom_loss()` should do during the `backward()` pass in `SegmentationLoss()`. What is the additional input `derOutputs`, where does it come from and what should be the return value of `custom_loss()`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where you found the class `SegmentationLoss` in the MatConvNet package. I don't see it in version 1.0-beta25. In any case, to implement a custom loss function, you'll want to implement the forward and backward passes of the network. In the backward pass, you're taking derivatives with respect to (w.r.t.) weights and inputs. To get the derivative w.r.t. the weights, you need the backpropagated error signal to the node the weight is pointing to, which I believe is what `derOutputs` represents. Take a look at documentation in the `eval` function for a more thorough understanding.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian Thanks! The class `SegmentationLoss` is in the fully convolutional network package.